# delete last value of a splitted string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to look into a hash but the last value should be there :

**params send to controller**

```
{
 "user"=>{"email"=>"a@a.fr,
 lol@lol.fr"}
```

**method**

```
def set_users
    @users = params[:user][:email]
    logger.debug "#{@users.split(",").each { |e| puts e }}"
end
```

**logs**

```
a@a.fr
 lol@lol.fr
["a@a.fr", " lol@lol.fr"]
```

The point is that #each takes a value (["a@a.fr", " lol@lol.fr"]) which is not in the hash. How can I apply #each to the whole hash except on this value

Comment: What is `last` in `delete(last)` - a local variable?

Comment: Actually it's a mistake, juste ignore .delete(last)

Comment: You can edit your question to fix it (and maybe clarify your requirements).

Answer (score 2):

I'd do:

```
@users.split(",")[0..-2]
```

Namely, take everything but the last.

So:

```
logger.debug @users.split(",")[0..-2].join(', ')
```

---

Seems you just need:

```
logger.debug @users
```

Comment: Logs become : a@a.fr
["a@a.fr"], it's not what I want

Comment: @apneadiving I don't think the OP wants to delete anything from the array, the question is about the duplicate output because of `debug` and `puts`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the String#gsub method like this:

```
def set_users
    email = params[:user][:email]
    params[:user][:email] = email.gsub(/,.*/i, '')
end
```

Comment: Logs become :a@a.fr
["a@a.fr"]

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your method:

```
def set_users
  @users = params[:user][:email].split(',')
  @users.pop
end
```

Then you can use `@users` without last one and get last one's info by the return value from `set_users` method.

Comment: It returns only the value before the last one